# Ethj spring boot blockchain transaction app error the method subscribe is undefined for the type object

Tags: ethereumj

package org.web3j.web3jspringbootstarter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameterName;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.Transaction;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthCoinbase;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthGetTransactionCount;
import org.web3j.web3jspringbootstarter.service.BlockchainService;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BlockchainApp {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlockchainService.class);

private final Web3j web3j;

public BlockchainApp(Web3j web3j) {
    this.web3j = web3j;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BlockchainApp.class, args);
}

@PostConstruct
public void listen() {

    web3j.transactionObservable().subscribe(tx -> {

        LOGGER.info("New tx: id={}, block={}, from={}, to={}, value={}", tx.getHash(), tx.getBlockHash(), tx.getFrom(), tx.getTo(), tx.getValue().intValue());

        try {

            EthCoinbase coinbase = web3j.ethCoinbase().send();
            EthGetTransactionCount transactionCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(tx.getFrom(), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
            LOGGER.info("Tx count: {}", transactionCount.getTransactionCount().intValue());

            if (transactionCount.getTransactionCount().intValue() % 10 == 0) {

                EthGetTransactionCount tc = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(coinbase.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
                Transaction transaction = Transaction.createEtherTransaction(coinbase.getAddress(), tc.getTransactionCount(), tx.getValue(), BigInteger.valueOf(21_000), tx.getFrom(), tx.getValue());
                web3j.ethSendTransaction(transaction).send();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error getting transactions", e);
        }

    });

    LOGGER.info("Subscribed");

}
```

}

Where it says: "web3j.transactionObservable().subscribe(tx -> {" 
I keep getting the error "the method subscribe is undefined for the type object".  Does anyone have any pointers on how to fix this?